Finishing a Berachah when in doubt
If one said “Baruch Atah Ado-nai Elo-heinu Melech Ha’olam”, and then he realized that he shouldn’t have, because of a doubt as to whether he needed to make a Berachah, should he finish the Berachah, or is it better that he should not say a full Berachah possibly in vain?

This leads to the intriguing suggestion that if you start a blessing you are for sure not obligated in, you ought at least finish it with מגביה שפלים or סומך נופלים which we're all potentially obligated in each morning (but generally omit out of doubt)

@DoubleAA would you be yotzei מגביה שפלים with אמת ויציב and סומך נופלים with אתה גבור?

@Heshy accd to https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan,_Orach_Chaim.52.8 yes, but it's pretty mechudash

@DoubleAA I don't have a proof right now but I'm under the impression that if you begin a bracha with intent for one ending, you cannot switch it in the middle (say for instance, you realise you an avocado is ha'adama)

@Chani that is one side of a very complicated sugya, but for us the fact remains you have nothing to lose by trying the other opinion
