Can the words ״שתרגילנו בתורתך״ ever count as Birchas Hatorah?
The law is (Orach Chaim 47:7) that if one already recited the blessing of “Ahavas Olam/Ahavah Rabbah”, and recited words of Torah immediately after Shmoneh Esreh, he no longer needs to recite Birchas Hatorah if he did not yet do so. The Mishnah Berurah there explains that the blessing of “Ahavas Olam/Ahavah Rabbah” contains a summary of Birchas Hatorah (i.e. a prayer that we be able to learn and understand the Torah).
My question is: if one recited words of Torah immediately after the blessing of “Hama’avir Sheina”, would he not need to recite Birchas Hatorah, being that he already said ״שתרגילנו בתורתך״?

Do you think שתרגילנו בתורתך is a summary of birkas hatorah? Does it refer to Torah study at all?

@DoubleAA what else could it be referring to? Seemingly it is not just referring to Mitzvos in general - we mention that right afterwards with the words ״ותדביקנו במצוותיך״.

@Shalom I don't see how it's a summary of birkas hatorah, missing so many potential aspects. Parallel phrases can be poetic and similar. The silence of poskim on this suggestion seems clearly to align with me.

This also assumes random phrases within a bracha without a relevant chatima can work https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/145645/finishing-a-berachah-when-in-doubt#comment487646_145645

(This all assumes like Rashi etc. that ahavat olam works by accident. For the other side, that ahavat olam is the primary birkat hatorah and what we call birkat hatorah is an extra enactment for people who want to learn before it's light enough for shema, the question of random other accidents doesn't even start since accidents don't help.)
